# wpa_supplicant: where does it store its list of networks?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

With `wpa_cli list_networks` one can print the list of networks wpa_supplicant has (successfully?) connected to.

Where is this list stored? Is it possible to switch the store between two versions? I.e. one list with e.g. NetA & NetB, the other with NetC and NetD.